# The type [MyClass] may not be used in this context

Tags: c#, xml, serialization, xmlserializer

I have a `WebMethod` that returns an object with dozens of classes in using stock serialization and some custom serialization by implementing `IXmlSerializable`.  It works fine.  I have added a property defined as `Object` that can hold any of these classes.

Most of the time, this works - but when the new property is set to one particular class, the framework gives me the exception above (consistently).  Looking at the autogenerated serialization code, I can see in the `WriteX_XXX()` method the code for dealing with lots of my classes, but not the one causing the exception.  I don't know if this is significant, but this class uses custom serialization via `IXmlSerializable`, and that works in other contexts.

I've `XmlIncluded` it in the `WebMethod`, and added it in as an extra type to the serializer - but nothing has changed.  The only thing that has changed things is if I add an `XmlElement` attribute specifying the problematic type to the `Object` property.  However, this changes the serialization code to only cope with the type I specified - and I don't really want to have to add in hundreds of `XmlElement` attributes to this.

Does anyone have any ideas about this one?  I've trawled the web, but not found anything that helps...  Unfortunately, other than the real code (far too big to include here), I have not been able to reproduce this with a simple example.

Comment: Please provide us the entire class or the very least an example class that generates this error. You didn't even mention what `type` causes this error. You have not given us enough information to even begin to help you. **If you give us something to work with I will remove the downvote.**

Comment: Thanks for the reply, but please read my last paragraph - I can't reproduce this (yet) with simple examples, and my company aren't hot on my posting actual code.  At any rate, lots of stuff is wrapped meaning I'd have to post 5+ classes just to show you what was going on, and you'd have to understand that code first.  The actual type in question is called `Endorsement`, but this is one of ours and doesn't really tell you much.  Apologies for not being able to say much more - as I said above, I can't recreate this with trivial examples.

Comment: So what `type` exactly is causing this error.  The problem with your question is that, the error you give, is a compile time error.